# Visitors "do not have permission to view this content" on home page only

Tags: permissions

This problem started suddenly. The navigation and all the other pages are still ok.

I built a new home page, simply by duplicating my old one, and then set home page to my new page. That didn't help.

I don't know what else to try. Obviously, I need to fix it. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

https://evergreenartanddecor.com

Comment: It should be about options. Please check your page options and make sure there is no option about preventing users. Possibly it is limiting it to logged-in users.

Comment: Hector, or anyone else... I unchecked the Options box for Content Permissions, and it made no difference. The homepage is still not giving permission to view, and all other pages are available. On the page's Documents menu, visibility is set as "Public."